# Apache Ignite: Сache API vs SQL

Tags: ignite

What should I use **cache.put(key, value)** or **cache.query("INSERT INTO Table ")**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you properly [configured queryable fields](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-api#configuring-queryable-fields) for your cache you can use both ways to insert data into the cache:

1. Key-Value API as shown [here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/sql-key-value-storage#using-key-value-api).
2. SqlFieldsQuery as described [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-api#inserting-updating-deleting-and-merging).

Also, in case you would like to upload a large amount of data you can use [Data Streamer](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-streaming), which automatically buffer the data and group it into batches for better performance.

Comment: What's the difference between configuration using annotations and configuration using query entities? What way is more profitable?
For now, I'm using a configuration with request objects, but the annotations seem to be simpler.

Comment: @ChrisCross The annotations get converted to query entities. Use whichever is easiest.

Comment: @StephenDarlington What if I declare the key field via QueryEntity#setKeyFields and the rest of the fields via annotations? Can I use both methods at the same time?

Comment: Technically it works, but it can be confusing to mix methods. My preference it to pick one method and be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Any. Or both.

One of the powers of Ignite is that it's truly multi-model - the same data is accessible via different interfaces. If you migrate a legacy app from an RDBMS, you'll use SQL. If you have something simple and don't care about the schema or queries, you'll use key-value.

In my experience, non-trivial systems based on Apache Ignite tend to use different kinds of access simultaneously. A perfectly normal example of an app:

- Use key-value to insert the data from an upstream source
- Use SQL to read and write data in batch processing and analytics
- Use Compute with both SQL and key-value inside of the tasks to do colocated processing and fast analytics